# No matching function for operator with more template values than defined in class

Tags: c++

I'm building a generic matrix class that takes the minimum and maximum columns and rows as template parameters. It's defined as

```
// min_column, max_column, min_row, max_row
template <int minN, int maxN, int minM, int maxM, typename T>
 class ZQOffsetMatrix {
```

It has a matrix multiplication method that has the signature

```
template <int minN, int maxN, int minM1, int maxM1, int minM2, int maxM2, typename T>
 inline ZQOffsetMatrix<minM1, maxM1, minM2, maxM2, T> operator*(const ZQOffsetMatrix<minN, maxN, minM2, maxM2, T>& m1, const ZQOffsetMatrix<minM1, maxM1, minN, maxN, T>& m2)
```

I also have a test case which instantiates two of my matrix classes:

```
ZQOffsetMatrix<5, 8, 11, 14, double> A(...), I(...);
// ...
A*I;
```

But this makes the following compilation error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘ZQOffsetMatrix<5, 8, 11, 14, double>’ and ‘ZQOffsetMatrix<5, 8, 11, 14, double>’)
     A*I;
```

I'm taking 6 integer parameters in my template to write it, is the reason I'm getting this error that the compiler can't figure out which of the 4 values in each argument to plug into the template names?

Comment: The problem is **not** the number of integer parameters, but the fact that a **parameter cannot have two values at the same time**! If you look carefully, m1 imply that minN is 5 and maxN is 8. On the other hand, m2 imply that minN is 11 and maxN is 14 as there are at a different position. Thus, is is impossible to find a minN or a maxN that is valid for both m1 and m2 at the same time.

Comment: @Phil1970 I think that's what bit me. I was wondering why a matrix class which uses size numbers as template params doesn't have this problem but that's because my class can have different minN..maxN ranges, by adding a number to both of them, and still represent the same matrix. A standard matrix class will only have one size which means only one number that's possible as a template param.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler has no trouble substituting the template arguments. In fact, it's catching that you are *using* it incorrectly. Following the rules of the matrix `operator*`, 2 matrices of the same dimension *shouldn't* be multipliable. (not counting square matrices). This would require at least one of the template parameters to have 2 different values at the same time, which is impossible.

On the other hand, multiplying 2 matrices of suitable dimensions, like this:

```
ZQOffsetMatrix<5, 8, 11, 14, double> A{}; 
ZQOffsetMatrix<11, 14, 5, 8, double> I{}; 
ZQOffsetMatrix<11, 14, 11, 14, double> Z = A * I;
```

would satisfy the `operator*`, and compile.

Whether this is actually what you want, or whether it's reasonable, is up to you to decide. The compiler won't figure that out for you.